# Csv To Shape Error

Tags: java, geotools

I have found a usefull tool to convert csv files into shape files with geotools:
http : // docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html#create-a-shapefile-from-a-featurecollection

But i have a problem running it, i get following error:
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project tutorial: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

The error comes from this line:

```
final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType(
                "Location",                   // <- the name for our feature type
                "location:Point:srid=4326," + // <- the geometry attribute: Point type
                "name:String"         // <- a String attribute
        );
```

My POM file is this:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>11-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
    <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>    
</project>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: that is a maven error so it can't come from the java line you mention :-) which version of maven are you using on which OS?

Comment: Win 8.1 + Maven 3.1.  i looked at the error line code: Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.feature.SchemaException: Error decoding srs